# OS X shell script to add/remove App extension

Tags: objective-c, macos, shell, dropbox, ios-app-extension

I am creating a FinderSync Extension for my application like Dropbox do. Now I need to register and unregister this extension from Extensions(in System preference) programmatically. 
Dropbox implemented this feature in recent release .

[image: Extensions Pane System Preferences]

How to unregister and register an extension dynamically using **applescipt**.

Answer (score 1):

Try pluginkit on the shell (.sh script)

```
# add it to DB.
pluginkit -a  "/Applications/YourApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/FinderSyncExt.appex/"
# enable it
pluginkit -e use -i com.your-application.FinderSyncExt
```